# How do I set the initial scene in a sprite kit project?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have two SKScenes `GameScene` and `MenuScene` and the default scene that appears when i open the app is the `GameScene` but I want MenuScene to appear first

I tried to change the code in GameViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

extension SKNode {
    class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
            var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
            var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

            archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
            let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! MenuScene
            archiver.finishDecoding()
            return scene
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = MenuScene.unarchiveFromFile("MenuScene") as? MenuScene {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

But it only shows a grey screen not the scene, is there something else I need to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your `MenuScene` an `sks` file? probably not, you just have the `swift` file as the scene.

If I understand correctly, the unarchiver takes an `sks` file and unarchives it, look at the "unarchiveFromFile" method, see the if statement, and the else returns nil.

you can probably do this:

```
if let scene = new MenuScene() {
```

instead of the unarchive. Otherwise make an `sks` version of the `MenuScene` file.

Comment: And how do I create an sks version?

Comment: @Zablah that, my friend, will need some googling. Buy you can create an sks file from Xcode go to the top menu, new file, and then pick sks file